# After clearing the Recyclerview's Data(ArrayList), onLoadMore event of EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener is not firing

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I need to clear the data of recyclerview because I want to show the fresh data from the server, I dont know how to clear the recyclerview without affecting the infinite scrolling

Comment: please write down your code

Answer (score 3):

Just clear your list your list in Adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged method.

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RelativeAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<model> mArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

public void clearList(){
mArrayList.clear();
notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}

just call the clearList() method when you want to clear list.
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution, the issue was I did not reset EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener counter variable which was basically calculating the logic for reaching last cardview of recyclerview.

There is another plugin which basically gives you method to reset  counter variable 
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView